# setting correct PTR record for domain and postfix email server

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, domain, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I have a problem where I recently figured out, that describes this output!

[What steps to do to set the DNS PTR record, is the IP in reverse in the name needed?](https://serverfault.com/questions/587989/what-steps-to-do-to-set-the-dns-ptr-record-is-the-ip-in-reverse-in-the-name-nee)

The zone of my domain is:

```
MYFUNDOMAIN.COM.    3600    IN  SOA ns65.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net (
                2014100519
                28800
                7200
                604800
                600
                )

; A Records
@   3600    IN  A   10.11.12.13
mail2   3600    IN  A   10.11.12.13
sites   3600    IN  A   10.11.12.13
voip    3600    IN  A   10.11.12.13
www     3600    IN  A   10.11.12.13
xmpp    3600    IN  A   10.11.12.13

; MX Records
@   3600    IN  MX  10  mail2.myfundomain.com

; NS Records
@   3600    IN  NS  ns65.domaincontrol.com
@   3600    IN  NS  ns66.domaincontrol.com
```

In this thread they say that the PTR record has to point in this case to:

```
13.12.11.10.in-addr.arpa  300  IN  PTR  www.myfundomain.com
```

why not directly to myfundomain.com ???

postfix hostname is listening is set to mail2.myfundomain.com

I have this headache because German providers like GMX, 1&1 want to make a reverse domain lookup and refuse to communicate with the server.

WHICH and/or WHAT correct PTR record would I have to set. I am not getting smart. 
As I know, the PTR record is not set at DNS (at godaddy), more likely from my datacenters provider where I received the static IP-Adress from.

I would kindly thank you, if somebody could tell me the setting the correct DNS PTR ressource record.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `thread` in this phrase `In this thread they say that the PTR record`

Comment: with thread i ment question...... open the url, then you see that the ouptut is the same that postfix gives me...

With thread I ment opening the url where the topic, subject is asked for help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PTR record is set by the owner of your netblock, usually the ISP serving the server in question. You will need to contact the owner and ask them to make the change.

If you manage the public DNS for the netblock, you will need to add the PTR record to the appropriate zone file. How to do this depends on the DNS service in use. (However, your example does not use public IP addresses. I assume that in reality you will be using public IP addresses.)

The PTR record can point to any hostname you desire, although you generally want it to match the hostname that the server identifies itself as. For example, if your postfix server sends an outbound message to a remote server and identifies itself as `mail2.myfundomain.com` in the SMTP transaction (i.e., `HELO mail2.myfundomain.com`) then the PTR record should ideally point to `mail2.myfundomain.com` with a corresponding A record that matches.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Yes, you were absolutely right...
In reality I am using a public IP-Adress. I contacted the datacenter, to make the ipv4 and ipv6 PTR records for mail.myfundomain.com.

(of course, myfundomain.com and ip-address) in this thread, are taken out my hat.....

But thank you very much, thas was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: SOLVED! Thank you very much Jonathan, the ISP who manages the zone has to make the PTR record. 

At 1st I didn't understand what you mean with netblock, but THEY have to add the PTR record in their zone. 

Thank you!