# "Bad PTR DNS Resource Record" when sending E-Mail from Shared Hosting

Tags: email, email-server, reverse-dns

I have a virtual server with one IP x and have multiple sites a.com and b.com running on it.

When accessing x in the browser, I get to homepage a.com.

Sending an e-mail from a.com to GMX is without any problems.
Sending an e-mail from b.com to GMX leads to following error:

host mx01.emig.gmx.net refused to talk to me: 544-gmx.net (mxgmx101) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available 554-No SMTP service 554-Bad DNS PTR resource record.

I contacted the hoster which told me to setup something called "Reverse Delegation" to point the IP x to b.com. But don't I just shift the problem?

What is best practice for sending e-mails from a shared hosting environment?

Regards,
Rokko

Comment: duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/587989/what-steps-to-do-to-set-the-dns-ptr-record-is-the-ip-in-reverse-in-the-name-nee

Comment: @Xavy I don't think it's a duplicate; it seems the author knows what he's doing, what a `PTR` record is and how to set it up. The question is actually: How to handle multiple domains in a shared hosting environment. He got advice, but thinks, doing so would "just shift the problem", and I think so as well. Maybe worth trying out would be multiple `PTR` records, but I (like many other people) doubt this would lead to expected results.

Comment: True, I've re read the question and you're right

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a single MX entry for every domain you handle on that server, say

```
hosteddomain1.com MX 10 mail.mycompany.com
hosteddomain2.com MX 10 mail.mycompany.com
hosteddomain3.com MX 10 mail.mycompany.com
```

and then create the PTR pointing to `mail.mycompany.com`.